# splitting a list and writing multiple files with R - plyr?

Tags: r, plyr

I'm breaking my head on how to write multiple files from each row of the input matrix, after some calculations. The code that I'm using now looks like this:

```
akl <- function(dii) {
    ddi <- as.matrix(dii)
    m   <- rowMeans(ddi)
    M   <- mean(m) # mean(ddi) == mean(m)
    r   <- sweep(ddi, 1, m)
    b   <- sweep(r, 2, m)
    return(b + M)
}
require(plyr)
akl.list <- llply(1:nrow(aa), function(i) {
                               akl(dist(aa[i, ]))
})
```

The akl.list that I create is too large for large input matrix and I cannot store it in the RAM. My idea was to write on files each matrix that I obtain in the llply loop. Is there an easy way to do that? 
thank you!!
gibbi

Comment: yes, seems similar...I've to try to adapt your solution to my problem! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `do_ply` since you want just the loop feature

```
d_ply(aa, 1,function(row){
             a <- akl(dist(row))
             write.table(a)           ## you save in a file here
           },.progress='text'         ## to show progress (optional)
)
```

Comment: I get this error:            Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @ agstudyI'm trying it...but I obtain a single value for each row. I need to obtain a matrix for each row. Anywya, what does the "1" stands for (means that d_ply must work on the rows?)

Comment: @Gabelins your aa is a vector of matrix? can you show me the `str(aa)`. d_ply works generally in grouped rows. Here 1 stands for works on all rows without grouping.

Comment: @agastudy...the aa matrix has an ID on the first column and then a number in the other columns. Each output file should have the ID.txt as name.

Comment: I added this in the code before the d_ply:
for (i in 1:nrow(bb)){
aa<- bb[i, ]
Anyway I cannot get the right result in each output. :(